# System call to read hardware info and cpu info in linux c ?

Tags: c, linux, system-calls

I'm learning system call and their behaviour. I have used message ques,IPC,mouse drivers related programs.Actually I need some sample code  in which I should read the hardware(cd fan,cpu status,sensors)and turnoff,restart my system  using systemcall. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: You want your own code? Its not a one size fits all. I did it as-well, and ended-up using different solutions (like parsing /proc/cpuinfo, /proc/meminfo, for hdd info i used the api (ioctl.h).

Comment: no any  code which has system call which handles hardware and powering operation of the system.

Comment: For CPU info on x86-based chips, there's a `cpuid` assembler instruction for you to run after setting registry `EAX` to a specific value. To implement this in C usually a few lines of assembler code is inserted directly (with `asm{ ... }`).